# Upload list of objects to mysql using Retrofit Android

Tags: android, json, base64, retrofit, retrofit2

I have an ArrayList of custom objects, each with about 10 fields, that I already managed to upload to our server. The problem is that one of the fields is a String which contains a Base64-encoded string that I converted from a file, which the Retrofit Gson creater does not seem to like. This problem could be solved by just sending all the fields without the image, and then after that upload all the images using ftp, but it would be so much easier if I could just put the image in the object somehow.

Question: How can I send a Base64-encoded string as a field inside a custom object to a url using Retrofit?

Comment: What is the problem when you're trying to create the object with Gson?

Answer (score 1):

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/UploadImages")
Call<ResponseBody> postImages(@Body ArrayListImage img);

//POJO CLASS

public class ArrayListImage {
    @SerializedName("image")
    @Expose
    private ArrayList<String> image;
    public ArrayListImage(ArrayList<String> image) {
        this.image=image;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is the `RequestBody` code which i use to upload file using `Retrofit`:

```
RequestBody lRequestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);
MultipartBody.Part lFile = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", file.getName(), lRequestBody);
MultipartBody.Part title = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("title", file.getName());
MultipartBody.Part lFilenamebase64 = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("filenamebase64", base64EncodedFileName);
```

To encode file name:

```
String base64EncodedFileName = Base64.encodeToString(file.getName().getBytes(Charsets.UTF_8), Base64.URL_SAFE | Base64.NO_WRAP);
```

I defined the api like:

```
@Multipart
@POST("/upload") 
Observable<Response<ResponseBody>> uploadFile(@Part MultipartBody.Part file, @Part MultipartBody.Part title, @Part MultipartBody.Part base64EncodedFileName);
```

I hope it might help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Convert Object list into json string. 

Gson gson = new Gson();
String objListString = gson.toJson(objectList);

@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("********")
Call<JsonObject> sendObjectList(@Field("objListString") String objListString);

  And at the web end parse string into json.
  @enjoy
```